# Passing a ENV variable for LABEL in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

I need to pass an environment variable as LABEL in Dockerfile, my Dockerfile looks like below:

```
FROM nginx
LABEL maintainer="blabla"
ENV GROUP="default"
#Checking if Label values can be set from ENV Variables
LABEL group="${GROUP}"
```

below command to pass the build and run the docker file env variable:

```
docker build -t nginx:test_label .
```

```
docker run -d -e GROUP="mygroup" nginx:test_label
```

but when doing the inspect of the container, It is giving me label value as `default` instead of  `mygroup`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LABEL` sets image-level metadata, so it will be the same for all containers created from this image.

If you want to override a label for a container, you have to specify it using a special `--label` key:

```
docker run --label GROUP=mygroup nginx:test_label
```

Currently you're passing the environment variable to the container during running. The `Dockerfile` is processed on build stage. If you want to have this variable substituted in the image, you have to pass it on build:

```
docker build --build-arg GROUP=mygroup -t nginx:test_label .
```

Comment: But I want to add value in the `group` label runtime, not at the build time.

Comment: But LABEL is image-level metadata, not container-level. How do you plan to use it?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @Sergei. I am planning to use this LABEL values as a filter in Prometheus. Like different environment will have different LABEL values and I can put the filter without involving the developer. Hope this is making sense.

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer on how to set the label on a container.

Answer (score 0):

The docker image build and the docker run are two distinct steps. The problem here is that you cannot go back in time and build the image using a value that is supposed to be provided in a future step. You are instructing the image to `LABEL group="${GROUP}"`, which at build-time is indeed equal to `default`.

Later on, when you run the container and inject the environment variable, you do it correctly, but there is no instruction executed at run-time that tells the container to do anything with that environment variable.